# How to create a standalone SQL DB file to use with my java chat application?

Tags: java, sql, database, file

I'm trying to find a way to have just one .db file for use with my java chat app. The chat app is a total of 3 separate apps: HUB, Server, and Client.

The HUB server connects all other servers so users on the Client can all be connected. The db file needs to be on the server the HUB app will be placed so it can access it locally. The server nor the client apps will be on the same server so only the HUB app will have access to this file.

Any ideas on how to go about creating this standalone sql database file? I've seen some when I've downloaded minecraft plugins, so I know you can create an actual db file, just not really sure how.

I also need to have a way to set a password for this db file so it has some form of security.

Thank you

Comment: What type of SQL? MSSql? MySQL?

Comment: MySQL is the only one I know of, so that will be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question properly, but reading about Minecraft plugins and SQL file somehow tells me that you actually miss some basic knowledge about the databases and server communication and that is what the question is really about.

So to clarify.

**Databases:**

If you have a file which contains a database it is the SQLite Database. 
Here is the homepage of the project: [LINK](http://www.sqlite.org).
You can do further googling about the project to fully understand it.

However mySql is a separate database type, not based on sql files itself.

In both databases (and others too) communication with the database, when using java or other programming language does not imply sql files to be created and managed, but is usually done through ORM [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) mechanism such as Hibernate [homepage](http://hibernate.org) (for Java). This require you to read a bit more too.

**Database remote access:**

If you require an application to have access to the database, you should use on of the tools mentioned above. In your project it should be the HUB to have the access. Next, the proper way to encapsulate the access for servers and clients is to use Web-services [description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) to communicate the applications. It is a wide topic as well and you should consider studying it.

**Bottom line**

I believe you have never build such an application before and it is quite a step forward for you. Try to do one thing at a time and start with the HUB application and the database access. I believe you can find most of your questions answered either here or on the other sites, but it is quite hard to begin with no guidance at all so I would suggest you to find some experienced friend or a book about the Java EE applications to begin with :)

Hope it helps.